# does not print into the original file

Tags: python

in the last 2 lines the file1 stays blanks even with the write function. the rest of the code works flawlessly

```
def modQuantity(filepath: str,):
    model = input("Model: ")
    size = input("size")
    newquantity = input("New Quantity: ")
    file = open(filepath, 'r')
    tempfile = open(filepath+"temp", 'w')
    for line in file:
        sep = line.split()
        if sep[0] == model and sep[1] == size:
            tempfile.write(f"{sep[0]} {sep[1]} {newquantity}\n")
        else:
            tempfile.write(f"{line}")
    tempfile.close()
    file.close()
    tempfile1 = open(filepath+"temp", 'r')
    file1 = open(filepath, 'w')
    for line1 in tempfile1:
        file1.write(f"{line1}")
```

Comment: And you are sure that the original file isn't empty? Add a print just before writing file1 to see if you get anything.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to keep the temporary file, you could `os.rename(filepath+"temp", filepath)`

Comment: `file1.write(f"{line1}")` This is a useless use of f-strings.  Just use `.write(line1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the file so it hadn't chance to [flush](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-flush-method-in-python/) the content. You can use that method by yourself or close the file.

I recommend to use `contextmanager` so you can be sure file is flushed and closed:

```
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file1:
        for line1 in tempfile1:
            file1.write(f"{line1}")
```